# csv container for reading

Tags: python, signal-processing, data-processing, wavelet

I have a folder full of csvs. All the csvs have one column each. They all represent 3 classes of 3 signal samples  A, B and C (240 in total/ 80 per signal). I am developing a SVM model capable capable of reading every all the files in that folder.Due to the data not having the length. I am thinking of passing 10000 lines of each file to the model.
My question is, how can I have a reader that can be like the following?

```
 signal_data[1][:10000]
```

The line above would mean file number 1, up to 10000 rows.
Something like putting my all my csvs in a list of list of csvs

So for the signal part I can do something like this:

```
for i in range(len(signal_data)):
coef, freq=pywt.cwt(signal_data[i][:10000], scales, 'morl')
features =np.vstack([features, pca.fit_transform(coef).flatten()])
```

Comment: Why do you consider a file with one column to be a csv file (since it will have only have one value on each line/row and therefore not have any need for delimiters)?

Comment: @martineau. because, thats the format of the files. They have one column but not one row. Think of a excel file. One column, and 33000 lines.

Comment: My point was in such a degenerate case, there's no difference between a plain-text file and a csv file since there's no need to use a character, such as a comma (`,`), to separate multiple values on each line of the file since there will only be a one per line. This may be significant because it removes any special handling needed to handle the CSV file format—and therefore makes the problem simpler in that you don't need some sort of special "csv container". In fact a relatively simple list-of-lists would work. In other words, it seems to me you may be overthinking the problem.

Comment: @martineau. you are absolutely right. But i did by the way
 I did.  I sorted it out by reading all the csvs in my  folder and concatenating them, then transform to the data frame to a list of lists by using tolist() function

Answer (score 0):

I have done it by concatenating all the csvs that I read into one then, used to list function. But there is so many other ways to do it. I think its bit longer but here my solution:

```
path =r'C:\KingP\myfolder' # use your path
allFiles = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
frame = pd.DataFrame()
list_ = []
for file_ in allFiles:
   df = pd.read_csv(file_,index_col=None, header=0)
   list_.append(df)
frame = pd.concat(list_)
```

Then transposed the whole lot, and used to the holist function:

```
frame= frame.values.T.tolist()
```

Comment: You don't need the initial `frame = pd.DataFrame()` since you completely replace the value assigned with a new right after the `for` loop.